# How to modify the package 'newspaper' so that the heading is perfectly centered? And how to change the heading's font?

Tags: fonts, horizontal-alignment, titles, newspaper

This is the `newspaper` package that I've modified to remove the quote and location at the beginning of the title page and I have modified the side margins so the left side's margin is (roughly) equal to the right side's margin.

The problem I'm having right is why the date in the heading isn't centered. It's leaning to the right ever so slightly. Likewise, the middle header on subsequent pages also isn't perfectly centered. It is also leaning to the right ever so slightly. In addition, the circled characters in picture 1 are supposed to be "he" but, for some odd reason, the font Matthew Allen used decided to combine the two letters. The red vertical line is (roughly) the center line.

[The manual (CTAN).](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/newspaper/newspaper.pdf)

---

So, overall, how can I center the date in the heading of the title page, center the newspaper title on subsequent pages, and change the font to something similar, but one that doesn't combine letters together?

This actually my third piece of LaTeX work (the article in the pictures is my third piece, not modifying the package). So, this is pretty far over my head.

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

```
%%% Matthew Allen
%%% January 14, 2007
%%%
%%% This package provides a newspaper style heading
%%% for the standard Article class.  The default plain
%%% page style is redefined to accomodate headings 
%%% at the top of all subsequent pages.
%%%
%%% a good idea to use with this package is
%%% the multicols package and the picinpar package
%%%
%%% 

%*******    Identification   *****
\ProvidesPackage{newspaper}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

%*******    Declaration of options *****

% no options at this time

%*******    Execution of options   *****

%******     Package Loading   *****
\RequirePackage{yfonts}  % used for the paper title font

%******     main code *****

%define font for page title
\DeclareFontFamily{LYG}{bigygoth}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LYG}{bigygoth}{m}{n}{<->s*[2.5]ygoth}{}

%%%%%%%%%%% Define Text Dimensions  %%%%%%%

\setlength\topmargin{-48pt}         % article default = -58pt
\setlength\headheight{0pt}          % article default = 12pt
\setlength\headsep{34pt}        % article default = 25pt
\setlength\marginparwidth{-20pt}    % article default = 121pt
\setlength\textwidth{7.0in}     % article default = 418pt
\setlength\textheight{9.5in}        % article default = 296pt
\setlength\oddsidemargin{-17.5pt}

%%%% counters for volume and number %%%%

\newcounter{volume}
\newcommand\currentvolume[1]{\setcounter{volume}{#1}}
\newcounter{issue}
\newcommand\currentissue[1]{\setcounter{issue}{#1}}

%%%% set internal variables %%%%

\def\@papername{Committee Times:}
\def\@headername{Committee Times}   % because of the yfonts you may need both papername and headername
\def\@paperprice{Zero Dollars}

\newcommand\SetPaperName[1]{%
    \def\@papername{#1}}
\newcommand\SetHeaderName[1]{%
    \def\@headername{#1}}
\newcommand\SetPaperPrice[1]{%
    \def\@paperprice{#1}}


%%%%%%%%%%% Redefine \maketitle     %%%%%%%

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{-40pt}
\begin{center}
{\textgoth{\huge\usefont{LYG}{bigygoth}{m}{n} \@papername}}\hfill%  
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{0.1in}
\rule[0pt]{\textwidth}{0.5pt}\\
{\small VOL.\MakeUppercase{\roman{volume}}\ldots No.\arabic{issue}} \hfill \MakeUppercase{\small\it\@date} \hfill {\small\MakeUppercase{\@paperprice}}\\
\rule[6pt]{\textwidth}{1.2pt}
\end{center}
\pagestyle{plain}
}

%%%%%%%   redefine plain page style  %%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\ps@plain}{%
        \renewcommand\@oddfoot{}%                   % empty recto footer
        \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot                     % empty verso footer
        \renewcommand\@evenhead
            {\parbox{\textwidth}{\vspace*{4pt}
            {\small VOL.\MakeUppercase{\roman{volume}}\ldots No.\arabic{issue}}\hfill\normalfont\textbf{\@headername}\hfill\textrm{\thepage}\\
            \rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}
            \vspace*{12pt}}}%
        \let\@oddhead\@evenhead}


%%%%%%%%%%%  Headline (with byline) command  %%%%%%%%%

\newcommand\headline[1]{\begin{center} #1\\ %
            \rule[3pt]{0.4\hsize}{0.5pt}\\ \end{center} \par}
\newcommand\byline[2]{\begin{center} #1 \\%
            {\footnotesize\bf By \MakeUppercase{#2}} \\ %
            \rule[3pt]{0.4\hsize}{0.5pt}\\ \end{center} \par}
\newcommand\closearticle{{\begin{center}\rule[6pt]{\hsize}{1pt}\vspace*{-16pt}
            \rule{\hsize}{0.5pt}\end{center}}}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% End of Package   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

And here's the source code for my document, but with obviously fake text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{./newspaper}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{caption}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}

\date{Janurary 1, 1900}
\currentvolume{1900}
\currentissue{1}
\SetPaperName{The Example Times}
\SetHeaderName{The Example Times}
\SetPaperPrice{10\textcent}

\begin{document}
\maketitle{}
\byline{{\it\huge The Example Times}\\[10pt]
{\Large The Example Times}\\[10pt]}{John Doe}

\begin{doublespacing}
{\large Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc non tortor sed tellus aliquet aliquam. Phasellus dignissim fringilla est et luctus. Vivamus lacinia elit non eros tincidunt facilisis. Morbi sed eros nec orci ornare ultricies. Suspendisse vitae augue lorem, a ultricies est. Nulla at tellus ac augue congue adipiscing quis sed lacus. Nullam justo felis, tincidunt at consequat et, varius sit amet lorem. Curabitur congue facilisis mauris, sed scelerisque eros blandit a. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris consectetur risus sed dui tincidunt sodales at et ipsum. Pellentesque eleifend est quis metus auctor ac rutrum erat tempus. Nulla facilisi. Sed vitae felis non nibh fermentum convallis quis a dolor. Nam volutpat augue eget dolor consectetur rutrum. Ut suscipit, urna vitae pellentesque vulputate, leo tortor aliquet sem, vel tempor tortor nibh sit amet dui. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.

Quisque sed varius mauris. Etiam egestas lobortis nibh in condimentum. Etiam sem eros, fermentum congue porttitor et, porttitor et turpis. Phasellus at neque velit. Quisque consequat malesuada ligula, nec fringilla purus auctor vel. Suspendisse enim ante, tincidunt blandit tincidunt quis, venenatis sit amet purus. Integer id lectus vitae purus volutpat consequat. Pellentesque quis ante sed dui aliquam iaculis vel et elit. In iaculis mi eu arcu aliquet iaculis. Aliquam aliquet nunc in lacus tempor tempus. Integer commodo nisi nec nisi ultrices hendrerit. Donec ut rutrum sapien.

In eget viverra nisl. Sed volutpat placerat viverra. Etiam eleifend metus ut arcu tincidunt posuere at et erat. Etiam venenatis lectus non risus placerat at ullamcorper urna tristique. In consequat, magna id pellentesque vehicula, est odio pulvinar turpis, non luctus felis nibh id turpis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas sed risus ligula, sed ultricies velit. Fusce eget elit mauris, quis feugiat sapien. Nulla facilisi. Etiam lacinia suscipit scelerisque. Integer eget velit tellus, varius sagittis erat. Duis aliquam malesuada nunc, eu pharetra leo faucibus eu. Donec metus nibh, gravida non lacinia at, lobortis sed erat. Quisque auctor, magna ut lobortis faucibus, dolor sapien luctus dui, at consequat nisl elit quis tortor.

Curabitur sit amet turpis vel risus pulvinar sollicitudin. Phasellus eu dolor quis tortor interdum ultrices. Sed vel nisi libero. Quisque quis arcu lectus, sed vulputate tortor. Aenean dictum ultrices nibh eu commodo. Pellentesque nec sapien at nisl scelerisque accumsan at ut magna. Aliquam eu ligula felis. Phasellus interdum augue sed urna blandit rutrum.

Proin non nisi eget tellus fringilla tincidunt. Vestibulum convallis suscipit lectus sit amet rutrum. Nam a consequat dui. Integer malesuada, nisi vitae vestibulum ullamcorper, odio velit gravida ligula, vel interdum elit lectus sed mi. Fusce felis odio, varius id tristique ut, rhoncus tincidunt velit. Mauris orci risus, accumsan in hendrerit quis, pellentesque non augue. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.

Nullam egestas dui nec nisi laoreet sagittis. Nam laoreet imperdiet ipsum a sodales. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc rhoncus urna et mauris congue eu euismod eros semper. Praesent ut neque ut orci porttitor sollicitudin. Sed hendrerit dignissim magna at imperdiet. Nam nec diam leo, sit amet volutpat felis. Sed ac congue eros. Sed ac vehicula quam. Duis dignissim, enim sed convallis vestibulum, magna arcu rutrum ante, facilisis varius justo justo faucibus velit. Phasellus sem diam, vestibulum vel posuere eu, lobortis ac ipsum. Vestibulum ultrices, eros eu mattis varius, dui leo feugiat nisi, rhoncus consequat justo elit eget enim. Vivamus semper egestas nulla, quis suscipit nisl condimentum ac. Mauris placerat risus eu nisi luctus eget auctor mauris interdum. Ut imperdiet suscipit nisi, nec pellentesque velit adipiscing nec.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus hendrerit porttitor consectetur. Cras id mi vel purus vestibulum bibendum quis a enim. Nulla vestibulum vehicula justo vitae sodales. Donec nec nunc orci. Vivamus malesuada lorem sed lectus congue scelerisque. Duis ullamcorper neque quis leo pharetra id ultricies est feugiat. Proin blandit sodales erat, nec lobortis enim fermentum sed. Curabitur sit amet arcu ac elit posuere fermentum. Morbi mauris urna, rutrum eu tristique ut, placerat quis arcu.

Nullam quis erat vitae nunc sodales convallis. Aenean ultricies, velit et porttitor hendrerit, ipsum sapien iaculis nibh, sit amet interdum sem purus sit amet diam. Nullam venenatis rhoncus mi, at fringilla turpis ultrices at. Donec felis orci, fermentum id rutrum a, aliquet at est. In dapibus placerat lectus, ac rutrum velit dapibus blandit. Vestibulum luctus dignissim rhoncus. Nunc at orci a arcu rhoncus sodales.

Aliquam mi est, fermentum at blandit a, auctor ut tortor. Quisque pharetra faucibus urna quis ultricies. Maecenas elementum, dui consequat egestas semper, neque nunc pretium enim, sit amet molestie magna nibh ut enim. Aliquam nisi odio, pharetra auctor tempor sit amet, porta sed augue. Donec libero sem, dignissim ut vulputate non, malesuada nec dui. Cras scelerisque sollicitudin aliquet. Etiam in neque quis metus gravida tristique. Proin quis tortor et odio aliquam fringilla.

Etiam vestibulum, mauris ut rutrum ultrices, leo justo hendrerit leo, ac mattis nibh turpis eu est. Sed hendrerit libero id dolor tincidunt id convallis turpis pulvinar. Nunc blandit, orci quis rhoncus aliquam, nulla quam pharetra purus, ut ornare diam lorem non felis. Praesent lacinia, mi sit amet tempus molestie, nisl nisi cursus eros, non pulvinar arcu diam sed nulla. Vestibulum pretium condimentum dui, in luctus nulla molestie ut. Curabitur a neque a eros sodales feugiat vel non lectus. In fringilla leo in sem pulvinar sed bibendum justo posuere. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse euismod urna nec nulla vehicula ultricies. Cras tincidunt metus non augue bibendum a auctor urna fringilla. Vivamus odio elit, pellentesque vitae euismod sed, adipiscing rhoncus lacus. Phasellus pretium sagittis euismod. Proin malesuada tincidunt arcu, in placerat mi dictum quis. Aliquam facilisis dui in diam congue vehicula. Phasellus nibh neque, molestie a semper nec, tempor ac nunc. Aliquam erat volutpat.

Aliquam nunc erat, mattis non eleifend eget, varius id erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam porta eleifend felis eu bibendum. Donec eu eros feugiat quam blandit adipiscing. Etiam libero arcu, suscipit non ullamcorper quis, sodales eget dui. Aenean euismod sem eu leo hendrerit scelerisque. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Quisque vel risus ante. Nullam blandit odio sed lectus porta sit amet euismod odio suscipit.

In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras sollicitudin imperdiet lectus in tempor. Nam egestas, nulla sit amet porttitor gravida, mi nisi lobortis turpis, eget blandit nisl massa at libero. Fusce auctor mauris eget orci condimentum facilisis. Ut auctor, nunc in ultricies pretium, orci diam eleifend nulla, nec porttitor dolor elit nec ligula. Phasellus a vehicula urna. Integer dui odio, elementum sed ornare et, venenatis quis lectus. Duis lobortis ultricies odio, nec convallis est volutpat ut. Sed iaculis sodales massa, sit amet euismod ipsum lacinia at. Pellentesque molestie ligula sed dolor pharetra et ultrices ligula auctor. Mauris vel justo eget velit dignissim lacinia ac et nisi. In imperdiet velit at purus molestie facilisis congue mi pulvinar. Pellentesque quis eros mauris, sit amet tincidunt enim. Curabitur sit amet erat leo.

Quisque facilisis volutpat nibh at feugiat. Ut purus massa, ultrices sit amet egestas cursus, imperdiet a mauris. Cras et ligula sapien. Morbi tincidunt odio id tellus ullamcorper feugiat. Vestibulum velit nunc, tempor non luctus porttitor, hendrerit vitae lorem. Praesent diam purus, consectetur vitae placerat in, tincidunt vitae mauris. Etiam pellentesque, enim a faucibus bibendum, leo urna dignissim dui, vitae fringilla diam lacus in ligula. Nulla sed lacus at enim feugiat mollis.

Quisque quis felis magna, quis sagittis nulla. Aenean egestas nibh non dolor vestibulum tempor. Proin consequat orci vel risus gravida eu dapibus justo aliquet. Aenean rutrum sodales eros, vitae condimentum massa vulputate ut. In pretium ultricies purus et pharetra. Quisque ornare feugiat accumsan. Curabitur lacinia dictum dolor, ac fermentum nisl rutrum nec. Vivamus feugiat hendrerit elit, ut sollicitudin diam viverra et. Sed ut dui rhoncus nunc pharetra sollicitudin. Curabitur at turpis at purus dapibus fermentum vel eget massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque vel mauris at quam placerat luctus congue eget nisi. Proin iaculis tortor vitae dolor vulputate ut commodo velit dictum. Nullam sit amet purus lectus, sed ullamcorper tellus. Mauris non arcu erat, non adipiscing arcu.

Aliquam sodales aliquet tellus rhoncus ultrices. Nullam porttitor, dui eget sagittis tincidunt, magna est viverra urna, at tincidunt lorem metus id elit. Donec ullamcorper fermentum augue id euismod. Phasellus ullamcorper metus vel nulla congue faucibus. Donec suscipit, tellus vel pulvinar convallis, turpis diam aliquet quam, eu imperdiet nibh sem ac nisi. Nullam non tristique sapien. Proin id nunc arcu. Aenean vitae velit nibh. Ut sed tortor justo, eget fringilla odio. Vestibulum dignissim augue quis elit mollis eget dignissim neque congue.

Donec volutpat tincidunt orci consequat malesuada. Morbi auctor ante eu purus egestas sodales. Vestibulum quam nisl, pretium et dignissim sagittis, semper ut lectus. Duis commodo magna sed sapien ultrices ullamcorper. Integer quis quam metus. Sed eu mi dolor, vitae congue mauris. Donec tincidunt viverra tempus.

Nulla sit amet felis eu urna ultricies condimentum. Duis dictum dignissim mi id dignissim. Donec eget leo leo, vel egestas orci. Cras a lectus ac mi fringilla varius. Vivamus ac orci in lorem aliquet vestibulum in id dolor. In nisl velit, faucibus et dictum pretium, iaculis sed nisi. Aenean eu scelerisque sem.

Donec lobortis iaculis mattis. In rhoncus, nunc ac consequat commodo, nisi nibh porta nisl, vitae pellentesque ante ligula ac risus. Phasellus accumsan molestie arcu at placerat. Vivamus vel sem a mauris cursus egestas vel accumsan nisi. In accumsan porttitor magna at fermentum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur sed ligula sollicitudin lectus sollicitudin aliquam sed quis enim. Aliquam vehicula viverra sem non ultricies. Donec ac purus in nibh ornare volutpat eget sed mi. Praesent eleifend varius feugiat. Proin id enim sed diam fringilla volutpat vel dignissim arcu. Vestibulum pulvinar metus eu turpis viverra condimentum porta mauris euismod. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce non egestas dui. Nulla sit amet augue et tortor blandit rutrum.

Donec sit amet malesuada lectus. Nam at posuere nisi. Curabitur at dui eu ipsum semper condimentum eu at leo. Praesent iaculis odio nec mauris luctus ut mattis nulla dignissim. Nam porta dictum euismod. Vivamus laoreet, quam non tincidunt scelerisque, est ipsum dapibus erat, eget imperdiet ipsum nunc ac mi. Proin ipsum orci, facilisis sit amet posuere viverra, ornare sit amet augue. Nunc molestie porttitor arcu. Ut dictum porttitor purus, vitae aliquam justo sodales at. Fusce varius nisl sit amet nunc rutrum tempor. Proin nisi arcu, semper id laoreet non, commodo dictum lorem.

Nullam ac purus dui, eget sagittis est. Praesent aliquet accumsan suscipit. Sed in diam convallis libero fringilla congue eget ac felis. Vestibulum vel leo velit. Aenean id turpis libero. Proin molestie pretium nisl a tristique. Duis mi mauris, egestas quis interdum non, condimentum id libero. Sed scelerisque pellentesque neque, ac imperdiet neque dignissim in. Proin ultricies nunc vel ipsum lobortis porttitor. Sed adipiscing mollis nunc et dapibus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc sem libero, tristique ac scelerisque quis, semper a dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac lorem lorem.or, if you have any sense of morals or ethics. 

}

\end{doublespacing}
\closearticle
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the `The`: try writing `Th{e}`, this disables the ligature between the `h` and the `e`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{\small VOL.\MakeUppercase{\roman{volume}}\ldots No.\arabic{issue}} \hfill
 \MakeUppercase{\small\it\@date} \hfill {\small\MakeUppercase{\@paperprice}}\\
```

You should not leave a space before `\hfill` as `} \hfill`  leaves a space one word space wider then the stretch space. In this case it doesn't affect the centering as you do the same on both `\hfill` but better to avoid it anyway.

```
{\small VOL.\MakeUppercase{\roman{volume}}\ldots No.\arabic{issue}}\hfill
 \MakeUppercase{\small\it\@date}\hfill {\small\MakeUppercase{\@paperprice}}\\
```

However your main problem is that this does not centre the date on the page it centres it in the space between the volume number and the price. As long as you know the texts are short enough there is no possibility of overprinting, the easiest thing to do is just hide the widths of the outer texts:

```
\makebox[0pt][l]{\small VOL.\MakeUppercase{\roman{volume}}\ldots No.\arabic{issue}}\hfill
 \MakeUppercase{\small\it\@date}\hfill
\makebox[0pt][r]{\small\MakeUppercase{\@paperprice}}\\
```

(In general you should avoid `\it` as it is not defined by default and just there for compatibility with LaTeX2.09, so you could change that to `\reset@font\itshape`
 if you wanted). Also as noted by egreg you could use `\Roman{volume}` instead of `\MakeUppercase{\roman{volume}}`.

Comment: Wouldn't `\Roman{volume}` be easier than `\MakeUppercase{\roman{volume}}`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! I really wasn't expecting an answer for this question since I posted this so long ago.

Comment: @Donky yes just came across it in a "clean up" sweep over unanswered questions. Hope it is still useful answer (to someone at least:-)